# how to connect two dropdown lists and to put conditions in html and php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, web

how to connect two dropdown lists in html by putting conditions.

```
<p>Enter your source and destination.</p>
<p>From:</p>
<select name="from">
    <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
    <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
    <option value="murree">Murree</option>
    <option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<p>To:</p>
<select name="To">
    <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
    <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
    <option value="murree">Murree</option>
    <option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<form method="post" action="flights.html">
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

when user enter source and destination and click on search button it will go on different page on all different entries in two dropdown lists.

Comment: your `<select>` should have a `name` like: `<select name="from">` and all your `<option ...>` should be inside `<form method ....> <select name="from"> ..... </form>`

Comment: Your selects should be inside the form. And you're going to have to make a page accept the parameters when you post them to do what you want. You're not going to get given the code here, you have to show at least an effort to figure out the problem for yourself. There are plenty of examples of posting a form to a PHP page out there.

Answer (score 0):

First, your select dropdowns need to be INSIDE your form.

```
<form method="post" action="flights.html" >
     <p>Enter your source and destination.</p>
    <p>
        From:</p>
   <select name="from">
  <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
  <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
  <option value="murree">Murree</option>
  <option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
    <p>
        To:</p>
       <select name="To">
  <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
  <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
  <option value="murree">Murree</option>
  <option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search" /> 
</form>
```

Second, on the action page, you can use PHP to process the form variables, then output conditional content based on them.   Most likely the action should be flights.php, not flights.html